# php fails to find class on static method call

Tags: php

I am trying to call a static method using a string (kind of automatic eval that the interpreter does).

Calling the class on the code in the literal fashion works perfectly. The autoloader resolves the class loading and the method is called. However if I use a string with the same class and method name, it fails.

working example:

```
$object = \vendor\package\class::method();
```

non working example:

```
$full_method = '\vendor\package\class::method';
$object = $full_method();
```

Both examples are valid code, the first one works perfectly. The second one throws the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function \vendor\package\class::method() in...

The autoloader works well, even on the second case, checking the loaded classes, the file gets loaded. There is a limitation on using this "automatic eval" functionality that I am missing?

Comment: Why do you put in an extra variable? Why not use `$object = \vendor\package\class::method();`

Comment: This is a reduced example. The real code loads the string from an ini file, I need to pick the method from outside the code (it's a factory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `eval` in your case, because it more complex. You try to execute method from class at once. Better try to explode them by parts:

```
$temp = explode('::', $full_method);
$class = $temp[0];
$method = $temp[1];

$object = $class::$method();
```

Comment: Incredibly, this works. In the middle I found another solution using ReflectionMethod. I will put it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
    $stringExploded = explode('::', $classBuilderMethod);            
    $ReflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($stringExploded[0], $stringExploded[1]);
    $object = $ReflectionMethod->invoke(null); // the parameter is null because the method is static
```